# Powershell "Start-process" not running as scheduled task

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-2.0

Have two powershell scripts that I edited from XP to run in Win Server 2k8 R2.

They run fine when executed by manually in powershell, but if scheduled and run as domain admin, they perform all file operations they're supposed to; except they don't do a start-process that sends the file to the SFTP site it needs to go to.

They're launched by running powershell.exe with arguments as such:

```
-noprofile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -file C:\Users\administrator\Documents\script1.ps1
```

Again, like I mentioned previously, they run fine and launch the `start-process` as requested if you manually run them and only run the file operations if they're scheduled and skip the start-process.

The `start-process` is as follows:

```
start-process -FilePath "c:\Program Files (x86)\Tumbleweed\STClient\stclient.exe" -ArgumentList "httpsu://www.securesiteexample.org/incoming/ $filename /prefNoAskSched /hidden /log /Remote-Site return /quitWhenDone"
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Add some code to check to make sure the process is getting launched.

```
$FileName = 'c:\test\test.txt';
$ArgumentList = "httpsu://www.securesiteexample.org/incoming/ $filename /prefNoAskSched /hidden /log /Remote-Site return /quitWhenDone";
$ExePath = 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Tumbleweed\STClient\stclient.exe';

$Process = Start-Process -FilePath $ExePath -ArgumentList $ArgumentList -PassThru;

# If $Process variable is null, then something went wrong ...
if (!$Process) {
    # Process did not start correctly! Write the most recent error to a file
    Add-Content -Path $env:windir\temp\sftp.log -Value $Error[0];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that tidbit, integrated it and ran the job as a powershell, worked fine, uploading the file. No errors output. Ran as scheduled task, move the files around didn't upload and no errors output. So still puzzling to me.

Answer (score 0):

In your Task, go to *Actions* pane, edit and remove anything from *start in* field.

Comment: Nothing is in the "start in" field. Only the Program/script which is powershell.exe and then the arguments as posted above.